# How to avoid zig-zag plot when using geom_line with color and linetype

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a relatively large dataset that I can share [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ga42rg8ch3hd9fy/datos.csv?dl=0).

I am trying to plot all the lines (not just one: e.g. a mean or a median) corresponding to the values of y over x = G, with the data grouped by I and P; so that the levels of the variable I appear with a different colour and the levels of the variable P appear with a different line type.

The problem I have is that the graph I get is a zig-zag line graph along the x-axis. The aim, obviously, is to have a line for each combination of data, avoiding the zig-zag. I have read that this problem could be related to the way the data is grouped. I have tried several combinations of data grouping using `group` but I can't solve the problem.

The code I use is as follows:

```
#Selecting colours
colours<-brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")[c(9,11,1)]    

#Creating plot
data %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = G, y = y, color = I, linetype=P)) +
      geom_line(aes(linetype=P,color=I),size=0.2)+
      scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed")) +
      scale_color_manual(values=colours) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by=25), limits=c(0,100)) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1, by=0.25), limits=c(0,1)) +
      labs(x = "Time", y = "Value") +
      theme_classic()
```

I also tried unsuccessfully adding `group=interaction(I, P)` inside `ggplot(aes())`, as they suggests in other forums.

Comment: Is sorting the data by x not an option? Sometimes a “zig zag” is correct...

Comment: Do some data points might share the same `G`, `I`, and `P`? Hard to diagnose any further without a data sample that reproduces the result and/or a picture of what you're seeing.

Comment: @Limey thanks, I do not know. Do you mean this: `data_2 <- data[order(G),]`, I tried that but the result is the same.

Comment: @Jon Spring, thanks. The data is shared in the first line of the question.

Comment: Is there any way to incorporate a sample of the data in your question so that it can live on after that link becomes inactive?

Comment: I think if you selected the first few time points and the first few observations within a given P/I/G group, you'd have a much smaller example that would still convey the point, and be `dput()`able ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @JonSpring's point:

```r
dd2 <- (filter(dd,G %in% c(16,17))
    %>% group_by(P,I,G)
    %>% summarise(n=length(unique(y)))
)
```

shows that you have many different values of `y` for each combination of `G/I/P`:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   P, I [6]
   P             I         G     n
   <chr>         <chr> <dbl> <int>
 1 heterogeneity I005     16    34
 2 heterogeneity I005     17    37
 3 heterogeneity I010     16    34
... [etc.]
```

One way around this, if you so choose, is to use `stat_summary()` to have R collapse the `y` values in each group to their mean:

```r
(dd %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = G, y = y, color = I, linetype=P)) +
 stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line",
              aes(linetype=P,color=I,group=interaction(I,P)),size=0.2) +
 scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed")) +
 scale_color_manual(values=colours) +
 labs(x = "Time", y = "Value") +
 theme_classic()
)
```

You could also do this yourself with `group_by() + summarise()` before calling `ggplot`.

[image: time series with one line per I/P combination]

There's not enough information in the data set as presented to identify individual lines. **If** we are willing to assume that the order of the values within a given I/G/P group is an appropriate indexing variable, then we can do this:

```r
## add index variable
dd3 <- dd %>% group_by(P,I,G) %>% mutate(index=seq(n()))
(dd3 %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = G, y = y, color = I, linetype=P)) +
 geom_line(aes(group=interaction(index,I,P)), size=0.2) +
 scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed")) +
 scale_color_manual(values=colours) +
 labs(x = "Time", y = "Value") +
 theme_classic()
)
```

[image: time series with 600 distinct curve]

If this isn't what you had in mind, then you need to provide more information ...

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, although the goal would be to reproduce all the lines, not just one (e.g. a mean)...

Comment: We would need another grouping variable in order to know how to distinguish which points belong to which line. As I've shown in my answer, you have multiple y-values for each P/I/G combination; how is the computer supposed to know which y-value at a given value of G to connect to a particular y-value at the next value of G (assuming both are in the same I/P group) ???

Comment: That's right. I thought I could solve that by using `group=interaction(I, P)`.

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker, this seems to be working. I was expecting a clearer graph, with each of the simulations forming smoother curves. But it seems that the y values repeat a lot, which creates this chaotic, geometric shape. Perhaps the best option would be to make a graph with geom_line or geom_smooth and display CI's. Thanks for your time, cheers,